# Dynamically generate registration forms based on the client URI in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

The client has requested that each URI should have its own set of fields in the registration form. Currently, in Keycloak, the registration form is controlled by the User Profile settings at the realm level, applying to the entire realm. To meet this requirement, I am considering customizing the registration flow based on the client URI.

Here is my proposed plan:

**Develop a Custom Keycloak Extension or Integration:**

- Write custom code to interact with Keycloak's API and modify the registration form generation process.
- The custom extension or integration will dynamically generate the registration form based on the client URI.
  [please check demonstration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEIMR.png)

To address this requirement, I researched the possibility of customizing the registration flow based on the client URI. My plan was to develop a custom Keycloak extension or integration that would interact with Keycloak's API to dynamically generate the registration form based on the client URI.

However, I have not yet implemented this solution as I wanted to gather feedback and suggestions before proceeding. I expected this approach to allow for the customization of the registration form according to the specific requirements of each client URI.

Before moving forward with the implementation, I wanted to seek advice from the community to ensure that this approach is appropriate and to explore any alternative solutions that may better address the requirement.

I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance. Thank you for your assistance.